# GKE node pool custom machine type CLI

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

Is it possible to use `gcloud container cluster create` to create a node pool for GKE using **custom** machine types (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/creating-instance-with-custom-machine-type)?

Instead of n1-standard-1/etc, I would like to create an instance with 4 vCPU and 8 GB memory (for example).

I know this is possible in the UI, but I want to wrap this `gcloud` command in a script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like you are trying to use *custom machine types* rather than [standard machine types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#standard_machine_types) and want to use [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/create) for it like `gcloud container cluster create`.

This is actually supported by a beta gcloud command and you can create a cluster with custom machines by specifying the machine type as below

> --machine-type “custom-{cpus}-{MiB-ram}”

For the example you have provided 4 vCPU and 8 GB memory, the command would be something like

`gcloud beta container --project [project name] clusters create [cluster name] --zone [zone name] --username [username] --cluster-version "1.8.7-gke.1" --machine-type "custom-4-8192" ......`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

"gcloud container cluster create" command has a --machine-type flag.